# How to make a function that sets value to field of an object by key?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a function that sets the value of the object field by key. What am I doing wrong?
It all looks correct, and type hints work correctly, but it won't compile.

```
type Filter = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
};

type PropertiesOfType<I> = {
  [K in keyof Filter]: I extends Filter[K] ? K : never;
}[keyof Filter];

type ValuesOfFilter = {
  [K in keyof Filter]: Filter[K];
}[keyof Filter];

export default class State {
  filter: Filter = {
    foo: "",
    bar: 0,
  };

  set<T extends ValuesOfFilter>(prop: PropertiesOfType<T>, value: T) {
    this.filter[prop] = value; // error
  }
}

const state = new State();
state.set("foo", "1234"); // correct, as expected
state.set("foo", ["1234"]); // error, as expected
state.set("bar", null); // error, as expected
state.set("bar123", 123); // error, as expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typescript limitation. `PropertiesOfType<T>` gives all the properties that have values of type `T`. But then when indexing by that type in `this.filter[prop]`, i.e. doing `Filter[PropertiesOfType<T>]`, typescript has "forgotten" that these properties only produce `T`s and essentially uses `Filter[keyof Filter]`. This then produces a type error, as you can't always assign a `T` to that.

In different words from one of the typescript developers on [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40832#issuecomment-700855576):

> The problem here is that we don't have the higher-order reasoning to say "If a key came from an operation that filters out keys that aren't strings, then indexing by that key must have produced a string". The FilterProperties type is effectively logically opaque from TS's point of view.

#### What you can do instead is the following:

```js
type Filter = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
};

export default class State {
  filter: Filter = {
    foo: "",
    bar: 0,
  };

  set<K extends keyof Filter>(prop: K, value: Filter[K]) {
    this.filter[prop] = value;
  }
}

const state = new State();
state.set("foo", "1234"); // correct, as expected
state.set("foo", ["1234"]); // error, as expected
state.set("bar", null); // error, as expected
state.set("bar123", 123); // error, as expected
```

([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATlAvFA3gKClAMwHsiAuKAZ2BTgDsBzAbjygCMBDFc2gVwFtWqZgF9mOCAA8wRFMCgATCAXY8kUAMYJ2FClADKwdsmwsCiZF1jnUGE-nzEyUAETOANC3wdLABg-5RHBYKCGAAHgBpKElkWnldAGsIECICKyRUAD4ACjAUIjByCLcoADd2BB4IcngMlABtCIBdAEo7e2AACzgKADozOvq8gqbbcsqIZgCcYSD1IloqSkNjTFoIAHd9FYhsluYqIwhekOBs50d3FwBGACYAZgAWZ32oAHo3jRkUCHVgEu00Skv2Q8hwh2QJ1C50uJXqzjuT2crUY70+qHyKABukkkD+EDBEOOp3O3iuvAQCFeH2iKEx2KBeNB4J2ULOzm8iKuiOp6LpMgZuJBBJwQA))

The high-level difference is that **instead of being generic in the value type** and extracting properties that match that type (via `PropertiesOfType<T>`), **be generic in the property** and use it to extract its value type (via `Filter[K]`).